# convert ascii representing hex values to binary data

Tags: bash, binary, hex, ascii

I'm searching a way to convert ascii data representing hex values to binary files.
In detail, all communication on a serial port to a connected def vice (in this case a GPS receiver) is been logged by converting the hex values to strings.
What I'm looking for is a way to convert this data back to binary data.
Basically I'm able to do this running HxD editor and past the string extracted from the log.
[HxD representation of 2 line logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRUxb.png)

What I would like to do is being able to do this on command line to not need manually to copy/paste the test to the hex editor.

The lines always start wi B562 followed by values e.g. 06 which in such case should result in an output (represented as string) of 'µb.'

As an example I'm edding a file which contains the data I want to convert, and athe resulting file as it is written by the HxD editor. This resulting file can be opened and replayed by a tool provided by u.blox.com called u-center. It shows the satelite informations being recorded ...
input file [log01.ublox.tmp](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GYAsHcKM517XoMyRPe4wzgHcQjFRfPzk)
output file [log01.ubx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15hpMjTQFl9PayHyzhVkA7WRPnT38mYSv)

Thanks for any support.
- Wasili

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Your question would be easier to understand and answer if you were giving an example of input file and a clear specification of the expected output. For instance, what is the separator between your input records? Newlines? And what separator do you want between the output binary values? Newlines? Nothing? On how many bytes your input (output) values? What endianness? Etc.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I edited the question and added shared files usable for this conversion

Comment: C would probably be better for this.

Comment: I know in C it is not a problem, but instead of starting coding I can also use HxD. To be able to use a command line tool I just asked if such way exists by standard tools available in Linux distributions or even better in cygwin :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to convert ASCII representing hex values to binary data:

```
xxd -r -ps log01.ublox.tmp output.ubx
```

Comment: @laiki well, the answer was posted by me, and Grant kindly corrected my English ;-). BTW if you find the answer helpful, please vote for it and accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the question. TIA!